# Density Scatter Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts

```
library(ScatterDensity)
library(ggplot2)

scp2 <- DensityScatter.DDCAL(
  dati$gap_xgb1_c.1, dati$PWV,
  nClusters = 12, Plotter = "ggplot2",
  na.rm = TRUE, pch = 12, Size = 1, xlab = "HeartAge-gap (years)",
  ylab = "Aortic
                          Distensibility (mmHg-1)",
  ylim(-0.10, 0.010)
) +
  geom_abline(
    intercept = summary(lm2f)$coefficients[1, 1],
    slope = summary(lm2f)$coefficients[2, 1],
    colour = "red", linewidth = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_abline(
    intercept = summary(lm2m)$coefficients[1, 1],
    slope = summary(lm2m)$coefficients[2, 1],
    colour = "green", linewidth = 0.5
  )
```

I cannot modify the 'ylimit' in the graph whatever command I try to use. I follow the instruction claiming '(Optional) numerical vector, min and max of y values to be plottet'. Can you help, please?

I tried the passing the following commands without success:

```
ylimit=(k1,k2)
ylimit=c(k1,k2)
ylimit(k1,k2)
ylimit=c(k1,k2)
```

Comment: Following the docs I would try with `DensityScatter.DDCAL(..., ylim = c(k1, k2))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()` or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

First, following the docs you have to use `ylim = c(k1, k2)` to set the limits. However, you are right that this does not seem to have any effect.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on the default example from `?DensityScatter.DDCAL`:

```r
library(ScatterDensity)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

x1 <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y1 <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x2 <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 2.5, sd = 1)
y2 <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 2.5, sd = 1)

dati <- data.frame(
  gap_xgb1_c.1 = c(x1, x2),
  PWV = c(y1, y2)
)

p <- DensityScatter.DDCAL(
  dati$gap_xgb1_c.1, dati$PWV,
  nClusters = 12, Plotter = "ggplot2",
  na.rm = TRUE, pch = 12, Size = 1, xlab = "HeartAge-gap (years)",
  ylab = "Aortic\nDistensibility (mmHg-1)",
  ylim = c(-.1, .01)
)
#> DensityScatter.DDCAL: Estimating Density...
#> Loading required namespace: pracma
#> Loading required namespace: DataVisualizations
#> DensityScatter.DDCAL: Estimating colors...
#> DensityScatter.DDCAL: Preparing for ggplot2..

p
```

[image]

But you can set the limits using `coord_cartesian` to zoom in on the plot (or use `+ ylim(k1, k2)` or `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(k1, k2))` which however will drop all obs. which fall outside of the limits):

```r
p +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-.1, .01))
```

[image]